# Programatically select and bind Sharepoint list items

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, bind

I have some code to bind SharePoint list items to text boxes. But I only got the code to bind one item. My list contains two columns (ID and Name):

```
*ID Name*

1 Steven

2 Joe

3 Henry
```

This code picks out the Name field from the first item (that means my textbox will show "Steven":

```
try
{
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    query.Query = "";
    query.ViewFields = "";
    query.RowLimit = 100;

    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Employee List");

            if (list != null)
            {
                 if (list.GetItems(query).GetDataTable() != null)
                 {
                     DataTableReader rdr = list.GetItems(query).GetDataTable().CreateDataReader();

                     if (rdr.Read())
                     {
                         TextBox1.Text = rdr["Name"].ToString();

                         rdr.Close();
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to select the rest of them names? I was thinking about an if-statement to check `if field = ID (1, 2, 3)` etc. but couldn't find out anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while loop and it should loop through all the "Name" values.

```
if (list.GetItems(query).GetDataTable() != null)
{
    using (DataTableReader rdr = list.GetItems(query).GetDataTable().CreateDataReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            TextBox1.Text = rdr["Name"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Addtionally you should be using a `using statement` to ensure that `Dispose()` and `Close()` are both called on the DataTableReader.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it solved by using a foreach loop, actually I didn't need the query.